# How to make focus or border after click disappear in PrimeNG

Tags: html, angular, sass, primeng

I have another issue with PrimeNg. I need to turn of a border after click on button. I have tried a lot of ways:

```
host: {
    ::ng-deep .ui-button-icon-only{
        border: none!important;
        background-color: transparent!important;
        outline: none!important;
    }
}
```

It's not working, even if I add `:focus`, same to `.ng-star-inserted` and `ng-star-inserted:focus`

```
*:focus {
    outline: none!important;
    border: 0!important;
}
```

That snippet is not working either, creating a new scss clss named nofocus and added to button give us zero effect. And there I have:

[image: photo]

I'm talking about that border around after click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to add `box-shadow:none` to element for disappear border

```
:host {
    ::ng-deep .ui-button:focus, ::ng-deep .ui-button:enabled:focus{
        box-shadow:none;
        -webkit-box-shadow:none;
        -moz-box-shadow:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> used ::ng-deep and add box-shadow:none to element for disappear border

```css
::ng-deep body .ui-button:enabled:focus {
    outline: 0 none;
    outline-offset: 0px;
    box-shadow: none  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each element has class ***.p-focus*** after selection, so you should rewrite this class.

For example for inputSwitch:

```
.p-inputswitch.p-focus .p-inputswitch-slider {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```